# Focus syntax for Tab

Tags: c#

Hello guyz can i ask for the right syntax for `Focus` this is what i want to be happen.
if i hit the Tab(keyboard) the focus from `userNameTextBox.Text` will go to `passwordTextBox.Text`and will highlight all the characters(if there is) so that i can change it all without using Backspace(Keyboard) i already know the TabIndex property. what i'm trying to ask is what is the syntax for Highlight all characters :) your help is very appreciated :) thankyou!!

[image]

Comment: must admit, nice design

Comment: i think we have same question btw thank you :) and Freelancer thank you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe for the Focused-Event of the Textbox. In the eventhandler you can select all text of the TextBox by doint:

```
private void OnFocused(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
}
```